# WebView iOS - Keep two WebView 100% synchronized

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Is there a way to have two webview synchronized.

I would like to display on a second screen using Airplay the same WebView but in 16:9.

I managed to create a separate window for the second screen (which is 16:9) and load my local html file but the actions on my iPad screen are not synced with this second screen.

I just have two independent windows.
I really want to use the second screen to display a larger HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

"Synchronized" is underspecified in the OP, but given the most essential representation of a web view's state is it's `request`, you could try the following: In the controller of the webView that the user is controlling (call it "webViewA"), declare conformance to `UIWebViewDelegate`:

```
self.webViewA.delegate = self;
```

then:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    UIWebView *webViewB = // presuming you have a way to get this pointer
    [webViewB loadRequest:request];
}
```

You can achieve scrolling synchronization (probably the next most essential part of state) by declaring the same controller as conforming to `UIScrollViewDelegate`, and then:

```
self.webViewA.scrollView.delegate = self;

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    UIWebView *webViewB = // ...
    [webViewB setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try that in few hours and keep you up to date. The shouldStartLoadWithRequest is called every time a click appends or not ? Because for example if in the WebViewA I click and a modal bootstrap popup appear I need to have this same popup on the WebView B

Comment: I did the test and the shouldStartLoadWithRequest is only called on a new page load ( click on href) and not on basic interaction, javascript actions, modal popup. I really need to have full replication

Comment: Your comment clarifies the question to define "synchronized" as totally, 100% synchronized.  Sadly, this is not possible between two web views.

Comment: I edited the question to have 100% synchronized. Thanks for your answer so bad :(((